# Fecha de inicio y finalización siempre dá mi hora local en lugar de la fecha seleccionada en Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade, fullcalendar

Estoy implementando fullcalendar con Laravel, al momento de hacer click en cualquier día del calendario me arroja la hora local, da igual el día que seleccione, ejemplo (si doy click en el día 31 de diciembre me muestra la fecha de hoy que seria el 30).

Ya implementé los archivos (fullcalendar, moment, jquery, etc.) localmente y por cdn por si ese era el error pero nada, también estuve viendo videos pero lo único que encontré fue que pudiera estar formateando mal la hora de inicio.

El código es el siguiente:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/6.0.2/index.global.js"> 
</script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h3 class="text-center mt-5">FullCalendar js Laravel series with Career Development 
Lab</h3>
        <div class="col-md-11 offset-1 mt-5 mb-5">

            <div id="calendar">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="eventoModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" 
aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Guardar cita</h1>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> 
</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title">
      <span id="titleError" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveBtn">Guardar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Mi script es el siguiente:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            aspectRatio: 2,
            //events:@json($eventos),
            selectable: true,
            headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            }, 
            select: function(start, end, allDays) {

                $('#eventoModal').modal('toggle');

                $('#saveBtn').click(function() {

                    var evento = $('#title').val();
                    var start_date = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    var end_date = moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    
                    console.log(evento);
                    console.log(start_date);
                    console.log(end_date);

                });
            }   
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
```

Esto es lo que me arroja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Un posible problema es que estás usando la función select del calendario para mostrar el modal y establecer el evento click en el botón de guardar. Esto se ejecutará cada vez que se seleccione una fecha, por lo que siempre estarás estableciendo la fecha de hoy.

Una solución sería mover la lógica de mostrar el modal y establecer el evento click fuera de la función select. De esta manera, el modal se mostrará sólo cuando se haga click en el botón y la fecha seleccionada se guardará correctamente.

ejemplo

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    aspectRatio: 2,
    //events:@json($eventos),
    selectable: true,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    }, 
    select: function(start, end, allDays) {
      var title = prompt('Event Title:');
      var eventData;
      if (title) {
        eventData = {
          title: title,
          start: start,
          end: end
        };
        console.log("inicio:",eventData.start.startStr);
        console.log("Fin:",eventData.start.endStr)
        calendar.addEvent(eventData);
        
      }
      calendar.unselect();
    }
  });
  calendar.render();

  // Mostrar modal y establecer evento click en el botón de guardar
  $('#saveBtn').click(function() {
    var evento = $('#title').val();
    var start = calendar.getDate(); // Obtener la fecha seleccionada
    var end = calendar.getDate(); // Obtener la fecha seleccionada
    if (evento) {
      var eventData = {
        title: evento,
        start: start,
        end: end
      };
      calendar.addEvent(eventData);
      $('#eventoModal').modal('toggle');
    } else {
      $('#titleError').text('Ingrese un título para el evento');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/6.0.2/index.global.js"> 
</script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h3 class="text-center mt-5">FullCalendar js Laravel series with Career Development 
Lab</h3>
        <div class="col-md-11 offset-1 mt-5 mb-5">

            <div id="calendar">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="eventoModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" 
aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Guardar cita</h1>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> 
</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title">
      <span id="titleError" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveBtn">Guardar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```